# Get nested div-elements from HTML-body with BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nested

This is my first project using webscraping and im am trying to get the odds from the table at the [this website (flashscore.dk)](https://www.flashscore.dk/kamp/f3kNE0fs/#odds-sammenligning;1x2-odds;fuldtid).

However, whenever i try to print the body I do not get the nested div-elements.
This is my current code:

```
import bs4 as bs            # BeautifulSoup4
import urllib               # UrlLib

# Url to scrape data from
url = 'https://www.flashscore.dk/kamp/f3kNE0fs/#odds-sammenligning;1x2-odds;fuldtid'

# Request link
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page)

# Get body-element of HTML
body = soup.find('body')

print(body)
```

I think that i have to access the nested div-elements under `<div id="odds-comparison-content">` but this does not seem to be the case for my code.

How can i get the odds in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded from another URL via JavaScript. You can use this example to parse the table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# https://www.flashscore.dk/kamp/f3kNE0fs/#odds-sammenligning;1x2-odds;fuldtid
url = 'https://d.flashscore.dk/x/feed/d_od_f3kNE0fs_da_1_eu'

headers = {
    'X-Fsign': 'SW9D1eZo'
}

soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser' )

for row in soup.table.select('tbody tr'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td')]
    print(*tds)
```

Prints:

```
 8.50 4.75 1.36
 8.00 4.75 1.36
 8.25 4.85 1.42
 8.50 4.80 1.42
 8.00 4.70 1.42
```

---

EDIT: To print bookmakers in the output:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# https://www.flashscore.dk/kamp/f3kNE0fs/#odds-sammenligning;1x2-odds;fuldtid
url = 'https://d.flashscore.dk/x/feed/d_od_f3kNE0fs_da_1_eu'

headers = {
    'X-Fsign': 'SW9D1eZo'
}
soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser' )

for row in soup.table.select('tbody tr'):
    tds = [row.select_one('a')['title']] + [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td')[1:]]
    print(*tds)
```

Prints:

```
bet365 8.50 4.75 1.36
Betfair 8.00 4.75 1.36
ComeOn 8.25 4.85 1.42
NordicBet 8.50 4.80 1.42
Unibet 8.00 4.70 1.42
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I am not sure where you found the new url? When inspecting the page (my url) I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: @Kenno I opened Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab (Chrome has something similar). There are all requests the page is making.

Comment: Would you mind also explaining how i can get the bookmaker for each row?

Comment: @Kenno I updated my answer. I found the headers in the Developer Tools, there are all headers listed.